# Program for string length in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

It takes in a string from the command line. prints out the length of the string. 
I'm mostly looking for tips and general convention suggestions 
But I'm open to any other criticism also. 
Roast it please thanks.

```
global _start

extern printf

section .data
    arg_err db `Invalid Arg Length\n\0`
    len_arg_err equ $ - arg_err
    arg_frmt db `%d\n\0`

section .text
_start:
    mov ecx, DWORD [esp]
    cmp ecx, 2
    jne _error_ext ; Args != 2? 

    mov eax,DWORD [esp+8] ;char** argv
    mov ecx, eax


_label:
    mov dl, byte [ecx]
    cmp dl, 0; read byte and comp to 0 
    je _exit
    add ecx, 1 
    jmp _label


_exit:
    sub ecx,eax ; subtract end addr from start addr
    push ecx
    push arg_frmt
    call printf 
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80    


_error_ext:
    mov ecx, arg_err
    mov edx, len_arg_err
    call _print
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80


_print: ; needs ecx as char* edx as char* len

    push eax
    push ebx

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80
    pop ebx
    pop eax 
    retn
```

Comment: Explicit loops are usually suboptimal in x86 ISA. Consider `repnz` prefix. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840755/minimal-opcode-size-x86-64-strlen-implementation) is a good starting point.

Comment: strlen.asm:40: error: symbol `_print' undefined

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> mov dl, byte [ecx]
> cmp dl, 0; read byte and comp to 0 
> je _exit
> ```

There are various alternatives, for example:

```
cmp byte [ecx], 0
je _exit
```

And:

```
mov dl, [ecx] ; note: BYTE would be redundant, but you can put it if you like
test dl, dl
jz _exit
```

For that loop overall,

> ```
> _label:
>     mov dl, byte [ecx]
>     cmp dl, 0; read byte and comp to 0 
>     je _exit
>     add ecx, 1 
>     jmp _label
> ```

This is a "2 jump loop", but it can be a "1 jump loop", for example:

```
_label:
    mov dl, [ecx]
    inc ecx
    test dl, dl
    jnz _label
```

Or:

```
    dec ecx
_label:
    inc ecx
    cmp byte [ecx], 0
    jne _label
```

([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095/555045) are some details about `inc` vs `add`)

For fast loops like this, having two jumps in the loop can easily slow them down to half the speed.

`repnz scasb` is an option, but it's not that great. Small loops like this can run in 1 cycle per iteration on most CPUs anyway, and `repnz scasb` is not better than that (often worse, such as 2 cycles per byte on Ryzen and Haswel). The special optimizations for `rep movs` and `rep stos` don't apply to `rep scas`.

There are faster ways to implement `strlen`, that are not based on byte-by-byte loops but detect the presence of a zero inside a bigger block, using SIMD ([example](https://www.strchr.com/sse2_optimised_strlen)) or SWAR ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11787810/555045)). That way speeds much higher than 1 byte per cycle can be reached. Perhaps some future processor would implement a "fast rep scas" feature in a similar way..

> ```
> mov ecx, arg_err
> mov edx, len_arg_err
> call _print
> int 0x80
> ```

This is mysterious, there is no `_print` function and there is a stray system call without selecting any particular entry point, or perhaps `_print` was meant to put a suitable value in `eax`?

Comment: It was another label I had defined I thought I switched everything over to use printf so I didn't include the function in my post.  I'll edit the post when I get home today. It just set things up for the print syscall

Comment: I'm having trouble googling these "SIMD or SWAR"

Comment: @DNS_Jeezus I linked some examples. I could link the general concepts as well but I get good results if I google for them

Comment: @DNS_Jeezus: One thing I'd add to this answer: `movzx edx, byte [ecx]` avoids a false dependency on the previous iteration. If you don't specifically *want* to merge a new low byte into the existing register value, use `movzx` for byte and word loads.  It's just a simple zero-extending load like RISC machines do, not a load+merge. (https://uops.info/ and [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502))